# Menu with li float:left not clicking

Tags: html, css

I have a site that has menu which is build using UL and LI with CSS doing the rest to make it vertical and stylish (ipayments.kz).

When I scroll down a bit from the top the menu stops being clickable (like there is no hover, or A defined.)

The HTML code is following.

```
<nav>
    <div class="container">
        <a class="brand" href="#">Instant Payments</a>
        <ul class="main-nav">
            <li><a href="#projects">Наши проекты</a></li>
            <li><a href="#solutions">Наши решения</a></li>
            <li><a href="#partner">Партнеры</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contacts">Контакты</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="langs">

            <!-- >>> [FREE] >>> -->
            <li class="active" dir="ltr">
                <a href="index.html">
                    РУС                                            </a>
            </li>
            <!-- <<< [FREE] <<< -->

            <!-- >>> [FREE] >>> -->
            <li class="" dir="ltr">
                <a href="index_kz.html">
                    КАЗ                                            </a>
            </li>
            <!-- <<< [FREE] <<< -->

            <!-- >>> [FREE] >>> -->
            <li class="" dir="ltr">
                <a href="index_en.html">
                    ENG                                            </a>
            </li>
            <!-- <<< [FREE] <<< -->
        </ul>
    </div>


</nav>
```

The problem is with the ul class "main-nav" which is following

```
    .main-nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-nav:before, .main-nav:after {
    display: table;
}

.main-nav:after {
    clear: both
}

.main-nav > li {
    float: left;
}

.main-nav > li > a {
    display: block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 72px;
    margin-right: 30px
}

.main-nav > li > a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #69d1fe
}

.main-nav > li.active > a, .main-nav > li.active > a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #69d1fe
}
```

I found the problem piece which is

```
   .main-nav > li {
        float: left;
    }
```

Unfortunately if I do display:inline the rest of the menu goes nuts. Is there any way to use menu properly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to give us the full code, it could be something else on your site overlapping your menu

Comment: Hi guys, found a problem, that was caused by hidden div, used for displaying popup window.

Comment: That what caused a problem

<div class="modal-dialog">, can't put too much code in here.

Comment: Was it overlapping the menu? Glad you solved your problem!

Comment: It was an overlapping popup window

Answer (score 0):

if you have used bootstrap then call "clearfix" class in ul(main-nav) or used this css and after that call "clearfix"

```
.clearfix:after {
      visibility: hidden;
      display: block;
      font-size: 0;
      content: " ";
      clear: both;
      height: 0;
    }
    .clearfix { display: inline-block; }
    /* start commented backslash hack \*/
    * html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
    .clearfix { display: block; }
    /* close commented backslash hack */
```

Comment: It was an overlapping popup window that I unnoticed. Removed with one that I use always and everything works. Got this site from another developer.